# No internet connection in app in Emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, internet-connection

I am developing a image application that fetches images from the internet. When I run in **smartphone**, there is **no problem**. I can see all images from the internet in my smartphone. On the other hand, when I run my app in emulator, Images are **not** shown. Besides, when I search from anything from Google(built -in emulator) browser app, I can see results no problem here. In the app the emulator does not connect the internet. How can I solve this problem? 
for images I am using

```
  public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
        try {
            URL url = new URL(src);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            return myBitmap;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // Log exception
            return null;
        }
    }
```

in new thread.
I will share this app on Google Play Store, Can it be possible that images are not shown for user's smartphone? Should I take in consideration this problem?

**EDIT:**
Logcat:

> 10-19 12:55:04.934 8783-10474/gc.wallpapertupac W/System.err:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/LazyList/498307152:
>   open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory) 10-19 12:55:04.934
>   8783-10474/gc.wallpapertupac W/System.err:     at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:452) 10-19 12:55:04.934
>   8783-10474/gc.wallpapertupac W/System.err:     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:87) 10-19
>   12:55:04.934 8783-10474/gc.wallpapertupac W/System.err:     at
>   java.io.FileOutputStream.(FileOutputStream.java:72) 10-19
>   12:55:04.934 8783-10474/gc.wallpapertupac W/System.err:     at
>   gc.wallpapertupac.ImageLoader.getBitmap(ImageLoader.java:158) 10-19
>   12:55:04.934 8783-10474/gc.wallpapertupac W/System.err:     at
>   gc.wallpapertupac.ImageLoader.access$000(ImageLoader.java:25) 10-19
>   12:55:04.934 8783-10474/gc.wallpapertupac W/System.err:     at
>   gc.wallpapertupac.ImageLoader$PhotosLoader.run(ImageLoader.java:113)
>   10-19 12:55:04.934 8783-10474/gc.wallpapertupac W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:423)
>   10-19 12:55:04.934 8783-10474/gc.wallpapertupac W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237) 10-19
>   12:55:04.934 8783-10474/gc.wallpapertupac W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
>   10-19 12:55:04.934 8783-10474/gc.wallpapertupac W/System.err:     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
>   10-19 12:55:04.934 8783-10474/gc.wallpapertupac W/System.err:     at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 10-19 12:55:04.935
>   8783-10474/gc.wallpapertupac W/System.err: Caused by:
>   android.system.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or
>   directory) 10-19 12:55:04.935 8783-10474/gc.wallpapertupac
>   W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method) 10-19
>   12:55:04.935 8783-10474/gc.wallpapertupac W/System.err:     at
>   libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:186) 10-19 12:55:04.935
>   8783-10474/gc.wallpapertupac W/System.err:     at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:438) 10-19 12:55:04.935
>   8783-10474/gc.wallpapertupac W/System.err:    ... 10 more

Comment: Post the Logcat of the error.

Comment: Does it show any error in LogCat? Can you post that?

Comment: Sorry, I will share now.

Comment: do you write Bitmap to sdcard?

Comment: or Emulator android version is 6.0+?

Comment: Yes, I am writing bitmap to sdcard

Comment: There is no sdcard on emulator is it true? Maybe the reason is this?

Answer (score 0):

The file `/storage/emulated/0/LazyList/498307152` does not exists, maybe because there is no sdcard.
You could try to store your images in the [cache directory](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getCacheDir()).